# Replace an Instance Metadata URL in AWS/Azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-ec2, cloud, metadata

Is there a way/WA to replace the http://169.254.169.254 address to a different address or a  domain in an instance?

Comment: Please share more information, this question is too broad.

Comment: Suppose I would like to access to my ec2 MD through curl http://example.com or http://10.10.10.10

Comment: _Why_ do you wish to do this? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Security reasons. Suppose one can access my ec2, he won't figure how to access my MD.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to connect the Ec2 instance to an Elastic Load Balancer and then reference the security groups to allow inbound connection only through the Load balancer. You can then use the Load balance dns which would be something like :
your-loadbalancername.aws-region.elb.amazonaws.com
Additionaly you can configure a domain name for the load balancer too.

Comment: Can I access ec2 Meta-Data service through ELB?

Comment: Sorry for the mixup your question was rather confusing. ELB is not applicable in your situation. The Instance Metadata URL is provided by AWS and it cannot be attached to any domain as far as I know.